# Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames | Node & Nginx

Tags: networking, server, nginx, ssl, certificates

Among several subdomains, I have node servers running on different ports. I have a subdomain called `alexa-service.healform.de`, which runs a node server that should execute some functions and requests. One function of this is a `GET` query of data provided by another subdomain, hosted on my server too - `oauth2.healform.de`. If I let this function run, I get the following error message in the terminal and that is also the curious part:

**Error message:**

```
Hostname / IP does not match certificate's altnames: "Host: localhost." Is not in the cert's altnames: DNS: ampinbaunatal.de, DNS: www.ampinbaunatal.de "
```

When I saw that, I thought I was asking AskUbuntu rather than Stack. The domains ampinbaunatal.de and www.ampinbaunatal.de are also hosted on my server and also have a valid SSL certificate issued by Let's Encrypt. But why does the function of oauth2.healform.de differ on ampinbaunatal.de? The domains have nothing to do with the function.

When I call the endpoint of the data, the function should retrieve, with Postman, I get a correct response. But as soon as I run the API query in localhost via the node server (I'm on Ubuntu Server 18.04 btw.), it somehow switches to the other domain and I get this error message.

**Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with the certificates? Both have valid SSL certificates. And why does he accidentally switch to the ampinbaunatal.de domain?**

---

**Nginx config for both servers:**

```
server {
  server_name oauth2.healform.de;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:51001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
  server_name alexa-services.healform.de;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:51002;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

---

**The function which gets executed due Alexa request:**

```
function getNextAppointment() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var options = {
      url: 'https://oauth2.healform.de',
      path: '/api/userData',
      method: 'GET',
      tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      },
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          'Bearer < Token >',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    };

    const request = https.request(options, response => {
      response.setEncoding('utf8');
      let returnData = '';

      response.on('data', chunk => {
        returnData += chunk;
      });

      response.on('end', () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
      });

      response.on('error', error => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
    request.end();
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the problem you describe has anything to do with the config you show. But it is not fully clear what you are doing in the first place, i.e. what exact actions you do, what exactly spits out these error messages etc.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Updated the answer containing the function which gets executed. You don't think that it has nothing to do with the server? But why get's a completely other certificate called?

Comment: *"But as soon as I run the API query in localhost via the node server "* - what destination URL you are using to call the code on localhost? Somehow it seems to use "localhost" and not "oauth2.healform.de" which causes the problems you see. And this behavior has nothing to do with the nginx configuration you show.

Comment: The destination URL is `oauth2.healform.de` as weird as it is. With localhost I meant, that both servers running on the same server. Kinda misspelling, sorry.

Comment: My guess ist that some of your servers on localhost:51001 or localhost:51002 will do a redirect to `https://localhost`. This will end up at nginx since it is running on this port but `localhost` does not match any `server_name` there and thus the default (like the first one) will be used. The certificate provided by this does not match the `localhost` of the URL.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Very relatable. Yes `ampinbaunatal.de` is my very first server block. You see any mistakes in my nginx.conf?

Comment: Again, I don't think that this has anything to do with the nginx.conf you show. Its likely more a problem of a redirect issued  by your node servers behind nginx.